# Tensorboard scalar plots forever loading

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to get tensorboard to plot my loss values, but the plots seem to load forever, never actually plotting anything. It looks like this:
[image]

My code, below:

```
model = init_model_1() # initialize and compile model

training_generator = DataGenerator(train, labels_train, **train_params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(test, labels_test, **train_params)

tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', write_graph=False, update_freq=10, profile_batch=0)

model.fit_generator(generator = training_generator, 
        validation_data = validation_generator,
        epochs=1,
        shuffle=True,
        workers = 4,
        verbose = 1,
        callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

I'm writing this on AWS's Cloud9. Tensorflow and tensorboard are all up to date.
The strange thing is, tensorboard *worked* correctly until one day, I tried to use line magic %tensorboard in my jupyter notebook to instantiate a new tensorboard instance for each different model I was training, instead of instantiating one instance at the very start. That made tensorboard not plot correctly as shown above, so I reverted back to the old version of my code when tensorboard worked...and it still doesn't plot correctly.
Any ideas why this is happening?
I've tried terminating and relaunching tensorboard after training is complete, and the size of the tfevents file remains constant, but to no avail.

Comment: The fact that was working before and then stop working is really strange, but what caught my attention is that you are using `update_freq=10`. This means that the callback will write the metrics and losses to TensorBoard every 10 samples, it's a really low value, very uncommon. Maybe this writing frequency is somehow blocking the interface update.

Comment: @n1colas.m Yeah - it's high, but this wasn't a problem initially, so I don't think it's an issue - I've tried decreasing log frequency but it hasn't helped. Thanks for your thought though.

Comment: i got the same issue, only spinning circles, any advice?